Change which pin is used for SPI SCLK
I'm trying to get a waveshare 4.2inch E-Ink Display Module Compatible with Raspberry Pi 4B/3B+/3B/2B/B+/A+/Zero/Zero W/WH/Zero 2W Series Boards 400x300 Resolution SPI Interface working on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W that already has a Pimoroni Keybow Mini on it.  I've got it almost working - I have the display on spi0 but moved the RST pin to GPIO 23 instead of GPIO 17.  The only issue (I think) I have left is to move the SCLK to a different pin, but I can't find a way to do that.
Is there any way to change which pin is used for SCLK on SPI0?
(It seems the Keybow is fully hardwired, so my only option is to mess with the display.)

maybe use a jumper

@jsotola In what way?  I can hook up the screen to GPIO 11 as well, but it messes up both the screen and the buttons.

The SPI0 hardware (for the Pi models you mention) only allows GPIO 11 to be the clock.  It can not be reassigned.
See https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi for the GPIO/pin map.
